# Delete button not working in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

My query is not working in `deleteartikel.php`, it doesn't delete anything out of the database.

In form.php I made a delete button but it doesn't delete the row itself. I can't find the mistake.

form.php

```
 <?php
include 'dbconnect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM artikel";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$row['Productcode']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['Product']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['Type']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['Fabriekcode']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['Inkoopprijs']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['Verkoopprijs']."</td>";
         echo "<td><form action='deleteartikel.php' method='post'>
         <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'>
         </form></td>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<!-- Footer navigatie -->
<footer>&copy;ToolsForEver 2017 alle rechten voorbehouden.</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

deleteartikel.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {

include('dbconnect.php');

$productcode = $_POST['Productcode'];

$conn->query("DELETE FROM artikel WHERE Productcode = '$productcode'");

header('Location: artikel.php');

}
?>
```

Comment: sidenote: form cannot be child of table

Comment: You're not passing the Productcode in the form.

Comment: and where is the name attribute for $_POST['Productcode'];

Comment: You have a history of off-topic or heavily downvoted questions and are at risk of losing your question-asking privileges. You should [read this before you post your next one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question).

Answer (score 0):

You never post the product code so the query fails, there is no value sent. You have to add a hidden field to your form:

```
echo "<form action='deleteartikel.php' method='post'>
      <input type='hidden' name='Productcode' value='". $row['Productcode'] ."'> 
      <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'>
      </form>";
```

---

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

In addition, as Fred pointed out above, a form cannot be the child of a table cell, so you need to refactor your code such that you have a form containing a table for each row.

Error checking in deleteartikel.php would have revealed the issue with the missing value for your query. Without error checking in the script you can find the errors in your web server's error logs.

Comment: need a name attribute for the post array Jay $_POST['Productcode'] - edit: ;-)

Comment: Good catch @Fred-ii-

Comment: I put my best glasses on today